# Повторное нажатие кнопки

Tags: qt, c++

Всем доброго времени суток. Может, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой:

```
if (learn == QMessageBox::No)
{
    Learning->show();
    lineedit->show();
    label->show();
    right_b->show();

    connect(right_b, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(learning_slot()));
}
```

Имеется такой код. Дело в том, что при первом нажатии `right_b` слот `learning_slot()` вызывается один раз, при втором - два раза, при 3 - три и т.д. Никак не могу понять, в чем дело. Циклов нигде нет. Зависит все только от того, в какой раз я нажимаю на эту кнопку. Такое чувство, в какой раз я нажал и выполняет именно столько кликов.

Comment: потому что при каждом нажатии Вы добавляете ещё одного слушателя. А сигнал рассылается по всем слушателям. Оно Вам нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно просто в `learning_slot()` прописать
`right_b->disconnect();`.